# How to plot a barplot using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

```
                 average
Young          0.01921875
Cohoused Young 0.07111951
Old            0.06057224
Cohoused Old   0.12102273
```

I am using the above data frame to create a histogram or bar and my code is as follows:

```
C <-ggplot(data=c,aes(x=average))
C + geom_bar()
```

but the plot is attached here.

[image]
I would like the bar heights to reflect my data on the y axis instead of where the bar is placed on the x axis, but I don't know what my problem is in the code.

Comment: Please make sure your question is properly formatted, so it can be understood. Also, provide a minimal working example, so your problem can be reproduced.

Comment: To set the height of the bar to equal the value use `geom_col()` instead.  `geom_bar()` set the height of the bar to the count of the items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a column with `rownames_to_column`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)
c %>%
    rownames_to_column('rn') %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = rn, y = average)) +
         geom_col()
```

---

Or create a column directly in `base R`

```
c$rn <- row.names(c)
ggplot(c, aes(x = rn, y = average)) +
     geom_col()
```

Or as @user20650 suggested

```
ggplot(data=c,aes(x=rownames(c) , y=average))
```

NOTE: It is better not to name objects with function names (`c` is a function)

---

In `base R`, with `barplot`, we can directly get the plots

```
barplot(as.matrix(c))
```

Comment: Thanks. With what I have in the data frame how can I make x = rownames and y = average without doing rownames_to_column?

Comment: @LXJ you can use `barplot(c)` directlly in `base R`.  with `tidyverse`, you need a column.  If you don't want to install `tibble`, then `c$rn <- row.names(c)` and then use `ggplot(c, aes(x = rn, y = average)) + geom_col()`

Comment: Great, thanks! If I use rownames_to_column how can I change the order of the names? The bar created didn't have the order I wanted. For example, I want the order to be young, cohoused young, old, cohosued old but the bar has a completely different order.

Comment: @LXJ You can change the order with either `fct_reorder` from `forcats` or `c$rn <- factor(row.names(c), levels = yourcustomorderlevels)` where `yourcustomorderlevels <- c("young", "cohoused young", "old", "cohosued old")`

Comment: Thanks @akrun! All of them are very informative suggestions